# Word for when something takes place within the team

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If you wanted to provide training for a team you managed, but that training came from within the team, is there a single word you can use to describe this?

I.e. a senior member of the team is training the rest of the team, instead of an outside source.

Off the top of my head something like "innerteam training" implies what I want, but isn't a real word.

Ideally a single word, but a phrase could work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[Peer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peer) training".

> a person who is equal to another in abilities, qualifications, age,
>   background, and social status.

Comment: I really like this answer. It reflects exactly what is happening.

Comment: yes, but it could do with some elaboration.

Comment: Peer training suggests a flat, non-hierarchical structure.

Comment: @ugajin I agree, but that is kind of what I was going for. I only mentioned "senior" in my example as I made the assumption that it would be a senior that had more knowledge and therefore did the training. But a junior member may have knowledge of an area they could train others on.

Answer (score 2):

**In house**

> The definition of in-house refers to something done or operated internally rather than obtained from a third party or an outside source. When a company does its own printing instead of sending it out to a printer, this is an example of a time when printing is done in-house.

www.yourdictionary.com/in-house

Comment: That is something I didn't think of, but I suppose to me it implies within the company and not specifically the individual team.

Comment: I agree that at times it will need some help from context.